# Allowing Apache 2.4 access to workspace

Tags: apache-http-server, eclipse

I'm running Apache 2.4.6 on openSUSE 13.1 and I want to do a little web development, mostly php scripting. Therefore, I have installed eclipse mars for php developers. HTML and php files I put in the right directory as poited out by [this](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:LAMP_setup) instructions, i.e. `/srv/www/htdocs/` are indeed process and correctly, e.g. if I put newfile.php in that folder, I get the correct output on `localhost/newfile.php`. Now the problem is that the server cannot access files in the workspace. I have tried several approaches so far:

1. Symlink from `/srv/www/htdocs/` to `/path/to/workspace/`. This changed the output from the server from "404 Object not found" to "403 Access denied", even though I gave complete access starting from `/`.
2. Giving access to the directory by editing httpd.conf, like

   ```
   <Directory "/path/to/workspace/">
       Require all granted
   <Directory>
   ```
3. Setting up the server in Eclipse using the pathmapping.
4. Putting a new workspace in `/srv/www/htdocs/`. But already when I want to access a file at `localhost/workspace/file.php` I get "404 Object not found"

Yet nothing showed the desired effect. Since I only need the access for development purpose and the network is protected from outside even workarounds would be fairly acceptable to me, though a more correct way to do it would, of course, be preferable.

Edit: **Solution**

The issue that caused the problem was as simple as it was fatal. The openSUSE firewall blocked the port 80. Now the solution with transferring the eclipse workspace into `/srv/www/htdocs/` is working.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do what you want is almost always to **use some kind of deployment stage.**

For a purely internal or experimental setup, this can be something as simple as a script that runs `rsync -a --delete ./* /srv/www/htdocs`. (Specifying the source files using ./* reduces the risk of unusual file names causing issues during the copy process.)

You can then, if needed, amend the deployment script to make further changes, such as: make any applicable changes to configuration files, set ownership and permissions on files and directories, delete things that aren't supposed to be available to the web server (`.gitignore` anyone?), etc.

This way, the web server can be configured without any specific regard for the development side needs. Let Eclipse have things its way, and let Apache have things its way.

It shouldn't be too hard to configure Eclipse to run such a script when "building" the software, if you want a one-stop solution workflow.